# Using jsTree XML module

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, tree, jstree

I'm confused by jsTree's XML module.  I'm using 1.0rc2.  Specifically, jsTree converts XML to an HTML list-based tree using XSLT.  I couldn't get my XML to render so checked out the source code;  looks like the XSL is hard-coded into jsTree's code and one particular line means it will only work if you're root's child elements are called item;

```
<xsl:for-each select="$node/item">'
```

Are you meant to update the source code with your own XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ivan kindly answered this on the jstree google group, [here](http://groups.google.com/group/jstree/browse_thread/thread/dc8db4dc05ea8cb2);  It is by design. As suggested, I'll look into implementing my own XSLT that will allow jstree to consume (any?!) pre-defined XML.